# Convert string of strings to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I need to convert this string:

```
'"apple","banana","yellow peach","orange"'
```

to an array:

```
["apple","banana","yellow peach","orange"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java).  This is a simple variation.  `string.split(',')` gives an array of strings with quotes.  `array.map()` the result to remove the quotes

Comment: `JSON.parse("[" + my_string + "]")`

Comment: @Tibrogargan this is for JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Can the quotes strings contain commas?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Squint's solution using `JSON.parse()` is fine for this example, however, if there are nested quotation marks within your string, `JSON.parse()` will error. For example:

```
var str = '"apple","banana","yellow peach","orange", "Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson"';
```

You will have to be aware of what your data could potentially look like. There may be instances where the inner quotations are needed and so you can't use a global replace of the quotation marks nor JSON.parse(), and you would need to do something like this:

```js
var str = '"apple","banana","yellow peach","orange", "Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson"';
var arr = str.split(",").map(function (elem) {
  return elem.trim().replace(/^"|"$/g, ''); // regex courtesy of torazaburo =)
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Globally replacing quotes is heavy handed and may be incorrect depending on the data.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Agreed, this works for this OP's request, but is a limited case solution - squint's comment is a better solution. Although now that I think about it, the JSON.parse() solution will break if you have any nested quotations inside of the original string.. pick your poison

Comment: Better to split first, and then just remove leading and trailing quotes with `replace(/^"|"$/g, '')`.

Comment: @torazaburo Completely forgot about the ^$ in regex. Durp. haha thank you!

Comment: Your code does not work, I put it into a snippet. Please check.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeahhhh that was me not paying attention, good catch! Thank you. I have updated it so it works now.

Comment: Now, the only trouble is potential presence of commas inside values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, and that will be left as an exercise for the reader ;)